# Please help me- what should I do

Tags: muslim-practices

ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ

As-salamu alaykum This happened about 3 years ago when I was in my secondary school and it was a day like any other in the classroon.

We had religion studies (that was the subject we had) and I do not remember if it was Islam we were doing at the time nor do I remember properly how the discussion started,Allah knows best.

A guy said something along the lines of “I want to become a Muslim/ I’m interested in Islam” to which another guy (Guy number 2) replied with something along the lines of “why! No Christianity is the best” they both sat at the same table as me at the time. The first guy (that was interested in Islam) directed that statement to me, now I can not remember what I replied with but I know I didn’t handle the situation well and articulate which saddens me deeply because I should have done something. Maybe just maybe that guy could have reverted back to Islam.

A few days past and the guy announced he was moving back to his country, moving back to India to continue his studies, I never saw him again and at times I would wonder if Allah is mad at me for not trying to guide him. You see I didn’t want to force him like guy number 2 and I remember now that I had said to guy number 2 that guy number 1 shouldn’t be forced to pick Christianity if he doesn’t want to.

Sometimes I would remember not helping him and cry because I feel that I can’t do anything, but fast forward to just today Friday, 6 November, 2020. I was going through a friends following list. On Instagram to see which old friends I had forgotten about and I saw him, I clicked on his Instagram page and there is a picture which was about 7 hours ago saying that for the people who had forgotten what he look like this is him, I was shocked because it had been 3 years and I was wondering... What might Allah be saying, What night He want me to do. I got anxious and I was thinking that I couldn’t really help him back then but he appeared again so must Allah be testing me? I don’t know, I really don’t know what to do, I went to his message and was about to type, I was about to type if he was still interested in Islam, because he was years back but then, I thought should I randomly message him with that, I am not brave enough so I exited the message but then I thought if I messaged him maybe Allah might be proud of me, I don’t know what to do, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wa'alaikumusslaam brother, I would read this dua: https://images.app.goo.gl/nCviCHhEc8F5FMHk9
and then do what you feel is best, as Muslims if someone asks us something and we have the correct knowledge we should share it, and if you are unsure or doubtful it is best to stay quiet to prevent oneself from lying. In terms of your friend, I think it would be an amazing idea to start a conversation with him and ask if he is interested in Islam. Insha'Allah if your intentions are good, then Insha'Allah you will be rewarded. However, I would start the conversation off with a general message, like : 'How are you, how have your studies been ...' and once you have built a relationship with him and softened his heart than remind him of the incident and ask if he is still interested in Islam. Ask him about any questions he has and if you are unsure of any of the answers then ask a scholar or refer him to a reputable one. Any mistakes are from myself.

Salaam brother, Alhamdulillah for our deen becuase it is priceless.